# Query users with a filter and expand results in unsupported query

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to fetch a list of users from the Microsoft Graph API.
A lot of users don't have an email address, those users are systems users that I don't need.
So my query looks like `/users?$filter=mail ne null`

For another overview I need to show the manager of each user so I tried to add `&$expand=manager`. But doing so will result in an `Unsupported Query`.
When I remove the `filter` parameter it does work.
How can I only fetch relevant users and their managers in a single query?

*Optionally I'd like to only receive the ID from managers, as an optimization. I only need the ID because I already fetched all users and their data. `/users?$expand=manager($select=id)` is what I was trying but I get the error `Invalid $select properties.`*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `$select` inside `$expand` to select the individual manager's properties, the $levels parameter is required, such as `expand=manager($levels=max;$select=id)`. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-manager?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters)
[image]

For example

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=manager($levels=max;$select=id)
```

[image]

## Update

If we want to use Not equals (ne) operators on the $filter query parameter, we must set the **ConsistencyLevel** header set to `eventual` and, with the exception of `$search,` use the `$count` query parameter (either as a URL segment or $count=true query string). For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries)

For example

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=mail ne null&&$expand=manager($levels=1;$select=id)&$count=true
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  This does solve the `Invalid $select properties.` error.
I realize that I've posted two questions at once, and this query `/users?$filter=mail ne null&$expand=manager($levels=1;$select=id)` still results in the `Unsupported Query`

Comment: It looks like the Graph API has changed. This answer doesn't work anymore. I'm getting this error now: Request_UnsupportedQuery: Transitive manager's list is only supported on a single user, send the $expand request on /users/{id} endpoint